# using angularjs want to store assets which is checked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
 <div style="z-index: 1; position: absolute"ng-show="ctrl.company.selected">
    <div style="" ng-repeat="Asset in ctrl.company.selected.Assets">
        <div class="pd-5"style="width: 300px; background-color: white; border-bottom: gray solid">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check"/>
                {{Asset}}
            </label>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="check">{{Asset}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

above code is display asset on check now i want to store array of asset which is checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/3105/)

```
<div style="z-index: 1; position: absolute">
<div style="" ng-repeat="(index,val) in Assets">
    <div class="pd-5"style="width: 300px; background-color: white; border-bottom: gray solid">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" ng-click="addToSelectedOrNot(index,flag,val)" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-model="flag"/>
            {{val}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-show="selectedAssets.length>0">
<div>----------------Selected------------------</div>
<div>{{selectedAssets}}</div>
</div>
```

controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.Assets = ['asset1','asset2','asset3'];
$scope.selectedAssets = [];

$scope.addToSelectedOrNot = function(index,flag,val){
    if(flag == "true"){
    $scope.selectedAssets.push($scope.Assets[index]);
  }else if(flag == "false"){
    angular.forEach($scope.selectedAssets, function(selVal,selKey )
    {
     if(val == selVal){
       $scope.selectedAssets.splice(selKey,1);
     }
    });
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot its work for me i want exactly like this

Comment: @zubairsadiq please see the updated code, there was small bug in previous, also updated fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Another solution :

```
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Asset.checked" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" />
```

Then you filter Asset based on the checked attributes. And delete checked attribute while serializing to the server for a proper datasets.

The usage of `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` is because if you don't specify them you will have "true" and "false" as string value

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="check" ng-change="store($index)"/>
```

Your controller:

```
$scope.storedData = [];
$scope.store = function(index) {
    $scope.storedData.push($scope.ctrl.company.selected.Assets[index]);
    };
```

Assuming your $scope.ctrl.company.selected.Assets is of array type.

This code has not been tested. I hope you understand the logic i am trying to build here.

Comment: Your logic doesn't include if i unchecked it.

Comment: @Walfrat yes you are right. I am just a beginner. Didn't think it through